# Why method of get refs's value are different in DOM and Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ref

I was always confused by `this.refs.refsName.value` and `this.refs.refsName.getValue()` when got input value.

Here is the test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

class TestRef extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange() {
    console.log(this.refs.myInput.value); // correct
    console.log(this.refs.myInput.getValue()); //wrong
    console.log(this.refs.textFieldInput.value);//undefined
    console.log(this.refs.textFieldInput.getValue()); //correct
}

render() {
    return (<div>
            <input type="text" ref="myInput" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
                <TextField id='1111' ref="textFieldInput" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
 }
}

export default TestRef;
```

Pay attention to the `handleChange()`, Why getValue methods are different in DOM and material-ui Component?

[material-ui-TextField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field).

Besides, it seems refs is not the best way to get a dom or component element, any better practice to get dom and component elment？

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get value from component element is to access the event passed to the onChange handler function:

```
_onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
}

render() {
    return (<div>
            <input type="text" ref="myInput" onChange    {this.handleChange}/>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
                <TextField id='1111' ref="textFieldInput" onChange={this._onChange}/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
 }
```